# How to get opencv on electric precise (ubuntu 12.04)?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how I can get vision_opencv installed on electric/precise?  Thanks.

I'm running Ubuntu Precise (12.04) and ROS electric, and cannot seem to install opencv2.3 aka vision_opencv.  "rosdep install vision_opencv" fails due to there not being a "precise" build of it available, e.g.  "No installers found for rosdep [opencv2.3], OS version [precise]..."

I'm also unable to build OpenCV-2.3.1 separately;  a bunch of warnings, then:
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Steve.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31668/how-to-get-opencv-on-electric-precise-(ubuntu-12.04)?/) by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Electric does not support Ubuntu Precise.  See [1](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).  You will have to wait until ROS Fuerte support for Precise is added (in progress) if you wish to have a binary install and the relevant compatibility fixes.

Otherwise, you will to continue down the manual source build that you've been doing and deal with the compatibility issues that crop up.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the answer is to edit the vision_opencv/rosdep.yaml file to add an entry for precise, thus getting it to use the package libopencv-dev that you can install via Synaptic, etc.  For example, here's part of my vision_opencv/rosdep.yaml:

```
opencv2.3:
  ubuntu:
    lucid:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~lucid]
    maverick:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~maverick]
    natty:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~natty]
    oneiric:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric]
    precise: 
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv-dev]
```

---

Originally posted by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) with karma: 306 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4